# GWT - TOMCAT: service ClassNotFoundException

Tags: gwt, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I have a GWT project that is composed of multiple java projects.  The server-side code is in a separate project.  It works fine in eclipse.  But when I deploy it to TOMCAT I get a ClassNotFoundException error when it is trying to instantiate the service implementation.

I have exported the project containing the server-side project and have included it in the web-inf/lib directory...but it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add/copy all the `.jar` files, referenced by the project, to the project `WEB-INF/lib` directory.
Specially make sure to copy following jars.

- gwt-servlet.jar
- gwt-incubator-xxxxxxx-xx.jar (if referenced)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Maven to deploy your project?
Actually, I had the same problem. Eclipse is very different from Tomcat and much easier to use. The problem you are facing is because your main project is trying to call functions from another Project. Tomcat is unable to find where these classes are because of a misconfiguration in your multiple projects. 
In eclipse, the Google Plugin helps Eclipse to adjust any configuration errors or link between different projects via the project's properties which is not the case of Tomcat.
I can help you if you are using maven, otherwise I can just tell you to try and find how you can link the code of the different projects.

Comment: you can even try to add the jar of the other projects to the web-INF/lib as proposed by Shanta

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response...I'm not using maven.  I had forgotten to include a jar in my lib directory.